# Cloud sync for a shared filesystem used from multiple operating systems

Tags: backup, multi-boot, sync

I regularly switch between Windows and Ubuntu, and I use a third partition to store most of my documents and other data, allowing me to access it from either OS. I want to have all of my main documents (on the order of 50 GB) always synchronized to a server, both as a backup and to be able to access it whenever I need from my phone or someone else's computer.

How do I accomplish this? That is, what service would allow me to synchronize the same filesystem from two different OSes without issue?

I've found that I can trick Dropbox into syncing the same folder from both from both operating systems without going crazy, but their pricing doesn't work for me. Is there any other software that can do this?

- Google Drive- doesn't have an official Linux Client. Insync causes
  massive duplication trying to do the above.
- Odrive- doesn't support
  it and causes duplication.
- OwnCloud- I have an NAS I'm happy to use, but it seems that owncloud can't handle this either from forum posts.

I'm happy to use any solution that's under $5 a month for this capability and provides >50GB of storage, or that connects to my own NAS. I realize I could set up rsync to my NAS, or use something like rsync.net, but I'd really prefer a solution with a nice interface that I won't have to tinker with.

Comment: does your nas support bitorrent sync?

Comment: Can you sync directly to your NAS? Some NAS can act as a cloud-storage that you can simply sync directly to your NAS?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek My "NAS" is just a raspberry pi with a hard drive, so yes, it supports anything I want to install on it.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [bitorrent sync/resilio sync'](https://www.resilio.com/individuals/)s free tier for this. No external server needed, seems to work well for well for large, many files. Assuming you don't want oopsie resilience, turn off the archive mode, use a read-write share code and you're good. While the desktop clients are all or nothing the phone client lets you download specific files.

The linux client uses a webui, though I found it bogs down my original Model B RPi. It should be better on a 2 or 3.